# Will Ubuntu Software Center function in Raspbian OS?

Tags: software-center, raspberrypi

1. Can I install Ubuntu Software Center in Raspbian?
2. Will it work properly?
3. Will proprietary apps work properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might get better response if you ask on Raspbian Support Forums. As far as I know, Raspbian is based on Debian, not Ubuntu, and Debian does not yet include the Ubuntu Software Centre.

If you are just looking for a way to install software however, you may try Synaptic. Some guidance here http://www.neil-black.co.uk/install-a-graphical-package-manager-on-the-raspberry-pi#.Uj8BkUTK3Fg (usual disclaimer about third-party sites -- I'm not affiliated with that site, found it through google search)

Comment: I know that Raspbian is not based on Ubuntu. I also know about Synaptic. But Synaptic does not provide features such as reviews, proprietary softwares, commercial softwares etc. That's why I wanted to know about Raspbian and software-center. Thanks.